# How to handle AWS Lambda timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that generates thumbnails on S3 Put event. It works fine. But I want to handle the case when it accidentally takes longer than reserved time(3 sec).

It's because I'm fetching the lambda generated thumbnail by suffixing '-small.jpg' or '-medium.jpg'. If the timeout happens and the thumbnails are not generated, I must have an alternative image in my bucket.

Comment: Increase the function's timeout and/or configured RAM size. If your processing can potentially take more than the Lambda maximum (15 minutes) then you'll need some more complex solution. Also, rather than trigger on `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`, you should probably trigger on `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

Comment: @jarmod Can you explain why you recommend `s3:ObjectCreated:*`?

Comment: Because objects can be uploaded to S3 via mechanisms other than PUT, for example POST and multipart upload. If you just want to trigger on an object being uploaded, regardless of how it was uploaded, then use `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to increase function timeout you can edit in the general setting of your function. steps and screenshot below will explain how to do it.

1. Click on the lambda function hyperlink and click on General Configuration.
   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. click on edit [top right pane], and increase the function timeout.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv4wc.png): [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: thanks Praveen, but my question was on handling timeouts. To elaborate, maybe trigger another lambda function on "timeout event"? Or any method that takes a callback that runs on timeout?

Comment: module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
 console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
 try {
  // Function Logic
 } catch (err) {
  console.log('[Handler] - Main function: ', err);
  // Send the error to Third-party monitoring services
 }
};

Comment: You can write logic to your function to do like step function or any function to trigger if retry attempts crossed.

Comment: module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
 console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
 try {
  // Function Logic
 } catch (err) {
  console.log('[Handler] - Main function: ', err);
  // Send the error to Third-party monitoring services
 }
};

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that creating thumbnails will not take more than 15 minutes at maximum Lambda RAM (and correspondingly max CPU) but if you need to handle that possibility then configure your Lambda function with a [DLQ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/robust-serverless-application-design-with-aws-lambda-dlq/) and trigger subsequent processing of failed Lambda functions.